# Player who score 200 in t20 games?

Tags: cricket, trivia, records

Does anyone know the name of player who score 200 in single t20 game?

Comment: Nobody, player in t-20 match can be scored in 200runs.

Answer (score 9):

Nobody has scored 200 in an international, IPL, or T20 Blast match, with the [top scorer in a major T20 match](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/284198.html) being Chris Gayle, who [scored 175 for the Royal Challengers Bangalore](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/598027.html) in an IPL match.

However, as pointed out by Ale in a comment, it has happened at lower levels, with [Dhanuka Pathirana](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england/content/story/309582.html) scoring 277 in a match in the Lancashire league.
[Mohit Ahlawat](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2017/feb/08/indian-becomes-first-player-to-score-triple-century-in-twenty20-match) went even further playing for Maavi XI in a Friends Premier League match, scoring exactly 300 runs.

Comment: What about [this](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england/content/story/309582.html)?

Comment: @Ale, good point, I tried to qualify the answer a bit, still not quite sure exactly which matches the Cricinfo records cover

Comment: Lancashire isn't a first-class league, so its records aren't counted as the quality of play is too low. Same for the Indian teenager who scored 1009 (yes, over one thousand) runs in a match. Cool story, doesn't mean anything in terms of records.

Answer (score 6):

[Dhanuka Pathirana](http://www.espncricinfo.com/srilanka/content/player/50108.html) scores **277** in a [Lancashire's Saddleworth League](http://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/sport/cricket/pathirana-plunders-277-in-twenty20-game-1003419).

The match seems played in 2007 seems Austerlands - Droylsden (366-3)

[another source](http://www.dnaindia.com/sport/report-sri-lankan-smashes-277-off-72-balls-in-twenty20-match-1119878) - [another source](http://www.sportskeeda.com/cricket/sri-lankan-cricketer-dhanuka-pathirana-smashed-277-in-t20-cricket)

Answer (score 3):

Mohit Ahlawat has scored 300 off 72 balls in a T20 at a match in Delhi in February 2017.
It was a local match, not an international or IPL game.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/cricket/38904731